# Probability of getting between 490 and 500 sixes throwing a die 3000 times.

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

If I throw a die $3000$ times, what is the approximate probability that the number of sixes lies between $490$ and $500$?

I am trying to use the central limit theorem or Chebychev inequality to solve it, since I am just asked for the approximate probability.

I know $E[X]=500$ and Variance=$416.67$

Comment: Since there are so few cases, it's not difficult to use the Binomial Distribution exactly.  Even if you want to use the normal approximation for practice (or whatever) you should do it exactly to compare your results.  With the normal approximation, you need to remember to use the continuity correction.

Comment: The Chebyshev inequality will not give a good approximation, either here or in most other cases. Its use is typically to provide a bound

Comment: Do $490$ or $500$ count as "between"

Comment: @Henry Yes, they do.

Comment: @lulu I know, however I am asked explicitly to calculate an approximation. My problem is that when I try to use the central limit theorem, I want to calculate $P\{490\leq X \leq 500\}$, after standarizing it I get $P\{-10/\sqrt{416.67}\leq X-500 \leq 0\}$, which is $1$, since the probability is always $\geq 0$, right?

Comment: Why standardize it?  You have a normal distribution.  Just compute the probability that $X≤500.5$ and subtract the probability that $X≤489.5$ where the $.5's$ represent the continuity condition I mentioned.

Comment: Just to reiterate:  it's still worth doing it exactly.  It's good practice and, knowing the answer exactly, you can be confident of your approximation (or you can be sure it's wrong).  I should say, I don't understand the expression you wrote at all.

Comment: Isn't it a bynomial distribution? I have a random variable $X$ that is $1$ with probability $1/6$ and $0$ with probability $5/6$,I am working the sum of $500$ of these i.i.d random variables. I don't know what the continuity condition is.

Comment: Yes, I said it was a binomial distribution.  That's how you do it exactly.  My understanding was that you were approximating the binomial distribution with the normal of the same mean and variance.  Perfectly sensible thing to do.  The continuity correction is standard, you can look it up or, say, read about it [here](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/what-is-the-continuity-correction-factor/)

Comment: I am sorry but I still can't do it. Could someone elaborate on an answer?